# PHP, Remove duplicate and blank line

Tags: php, duplicates, array-unique

I get values from the `textarea` as follows:

```
2342
de20343
23094
zz900
234432
zz900
2342
```

I want to find duplicates (eg: "zz900" and "2342") and delete them. In addition, blank lines must be removed.

Is there a single function that will do this?

Comment: *Single function, both does not work together.* Which functions?!?

Comment: remove duplicate and remove blank line

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: My code can I include only later. Would you have a solution?

Comment: @anonym please up-vote the answer too. thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Check this, this is new code:-

<?php
$string_old = "2342
de20343

_
_
23094
zz900
234432
zz900
2342";
$array_by_exploding_through_next_line = explode ("\n",$string_old);
$new_array = array();
foreach($array_by_exploding_through_next_line as $key => $value){
    if(strpos($array_by_exploding_through_next_line[$key], '_') !== FALSE || strpos($array_by_exploding_through_next_line[$key], ' ') !== FALSE){
    }else{
        $new_array[] = $value;
    }
}
$string_new = implode('',array_unique($array_by_exploding_through_next_line));
print_r($array_by_exploding_through_next_line);
echo "<br>";
echo $string_new;
die;
?>
```

Comment: 1. OP also wants to remove empty elements 2. Not everywhere is `\n` == new line

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried exploding the text by a newline, and use array_unique to remove duplicates and use array_filter to remove empty lines?

Something like:

```
<?php
$text = '2342
de20343
23094
zz900
234432
zz900
2342';

$array = explode (PHP_EOL, $text);
$unique = array_filter (array_unique ($array));

echo join (PHP_EOL, $unique);
?>
```

Comment: You don't reindex your array, so the indexes could be: `2,4,5,13`

Comment: I guessed he just wanted to remove the duplicates and send or store it as a text field, not use it as an array; in this way reindexing is not necessary..

Comment: This solution is the shortest and works good, but when i paste the result in the textarea the cursor is at the top of the list, not at the bottom. So if i use a barcode reader to add a new line it will concatenate with the first line. how to avoid that ?

Answer (score 1):

This should work for you:

```
$parts = array_values(array_unique(array_filter(explode(PHP_EOL, $str))));
print_r($parts);
```

As an example:

```
$str = "
2342
de20343
23094


zz900
234432
zz900
2342";

$parts = array_values(array_unique(array_filter(explode(PHP_EOL, $str))));
print_r($parts);
```

Output:

```
Array ( [0] => 2342 [1] => de20343 [2] => 23094 [3] => zz900 [4] => 234432 )
```